# caret: Linear Model parameter estimates (mean and s.e.) via LOOCV

Tags: r, r-caret

I am wondering if there is a way to extract out all of the `lm` parameter estimates from the results of the cross-validation training runs from `caret::train()` with an `lm` model.

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mpettis/bf8d4a51e3e0082de9b553ff4f2cbfd2) of the `R` code I used to do some of this checking, where I directly access the `train()` output object, get the cross-validation data.frame indexes used in each cross-validation run.  But I was wondering if there were already functions that access this for me, because I would think that 1.) If it was a good or reasonable idea, the functionality would be there, or 2.) If the functionality is not there, my desire to do this may not be a good idea.

As a second part of the question, you can see in the gist that when I compute the mean and standard error of the single linear parameter over all of the cross-validation parameter estimates, that the mean of the CV parameter estimates and the linear model on a fit of the entire training data set match up well, but the standard error from the CV estimates is much smaller than that from the estimate from the single `lm` run on the whole training set.  Is that expected, or am I computing/thinking about that wrong?

EDIT: I think the second part can be found by reading [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression) .

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: This seems like more of a question for cross-validated. But it would not make sense to me to look at coefficients in each of your cross-validated models because they differ only by 1 observation. If you want to see if a single observation changes coefficients too much, you can use measures that capture "leverage" which are more robust than what you are trying. If the goal is to infer something about the true population value of your coefficients, I would suggest bootstrap confidence intervals instead.

Comment: @Chrisss : Well, I originally thought the same, but I got told it was too programming-specific of a question (some commented nicely, some were rude), which is why I moved it here.  Thanks for comment.

Comment: I see. Well, looking at your gist, it is clear you want to be doing bootstrapping. In the context of bootstrapping, your mean from the model, and *mean of means* from the sub-models (or bootstraps) are close because each sub-model produces a coefficient much like each other and like the model's coefficient (expected given that you are doing LOOCV). The standard deviations are dissimilar because you are comparing the standard deviation of the effect to the *standard deviation of the mean of the effect* in the sub-models. To bring this back to programming, the `boot` package is what you need.